# Track subdomain in Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have a landing page on `example.com` and a separate app on `app.example.com`.

**Should I use one property for both, or have a dedicated one for each?**

If so, how do I distinguish which is which?

For dedicated properties, I currently set it up like so in `Admin/property/data streams/stream/more tagging settings/configure your domain`...

- For `example.com`, I have `Begins with` match type setting with a value on `example.com`.
- For `app.example.com`, I have `Begins with` match type setting with a value on `app`.

Is this correct?

Comment: Did you found a solution to this? We also got a webapp under a subdomain like app.example.com and our landing as example.com

Comment: What I ended up doing is using dedicated tracking for each. It's just cleaner like that.

Comment: So you got a stream for your webapp and a stream for your landing page in one property? Can you track users between these streams?